# Operações com HashMap

Tags: java, classificação, hashmap

Boa tarde galera, estou precisando fazer algumas operações utilizando HashMap. Sou novo na área.

Eu tenho o seguinte map

```
protected Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> elementos = new HashMap<>();`
```

A primeira String é uma chave, o valor é um mapa que contém uma chave como String e um valor Integer.

Preciso percorrer todos os valores que estiverem neste hashmap, ou seja, todos os hashMaps interno.Com isso preciso fazer comparações e uma ordenação.
Exemplo:

`HashMap<"texto1",HashMap<"Cachorro", 3>`

`HashMap<"texto2",HashMap<"Peixe", 2>`

Ai faria uma comparação do tipo, "Se "cachorro" == "Peixe" -> Listafrequencia = (3-2);
Por último, de alguma forma, após este cálculo ordenar dizendo qual comparação de texto é menor.
Primeiro post aqui.
Java
`

Comment: Não entendi a parte da comparação, na parte que diz `Se "cachorro" == "Peixe" -> Listafrequencia = (3-2);` poderia explicar de outro jeito?

Comment: Então, ese Hashmap tem uma String como chave e um valor do tipo Integer. A comparação que eu falo seria: Se String for igual a String do hashmap, faça esta operação que está contido no campo valor do Tipo Integer do Hashmap ( 3 para cachorro e 2 para peixe no caso.) Obs, este número é refente a quantidade de vezes que esta String está em um determinado texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se esse é um exercício de aprendizado (faculdade ou curso) o enunciado completo iria ajudar, a forma que você explicou o problema está confusa. Segue alguma orientação:

```
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> elementos = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

    //percorre  a map
    for (String key : elementos.keySet()) {

        int total = 0;

        //percorre a map interna, agrupado por chave 
        for (Integer i : elementos.get(key).values()) {
            total=i+total;
        }

        System.out.println(key + total);

    }
```

Comment: Isso, desculpa se não fui muito claro, é que o exercício é extremamente grande e fiquei com dúvidas nesta parte. Porém já resolvi, inclusive usei algo muito parecido com o que você posto aqui. Obrigado.